# how to solve the error in this prolog code

Tags: prolog

What is wrong in this code

```
frequency(f1).
frequency(f2).
frequency(f3).

allocation(z1,z2,z3,z4,z5,z6,z7,z8) :-
    frequency(z1), frequency(z2), frequency(z3), frequency(z4), frequency(z5), frequency(z6), frequency(z7), frequency(z8),
    z1\==z2, z1\==z3, z2\==z4, z2\==z3, z3\==z4, z3\==z6, z4\==z5, z4\==z6, z4\==z7, z6\==z7, z6\==z8.

?- allocation(f1,f2,f3,f1,f2,f3,f2,f3).
```

syntax error: . or operator expected after expression

Comment: There is no syntax error in your code... Moreover, the terms `z1`, `z2`, ..., `z8` in `allocation/8` should be written with capital `Z`

Comment: Variables in Prolog must begin with a capital letter (or `_` if you want anonymous variable).

Comment: @lurker: **only** `_` is an anonymous variable. Say, `_1` is not. Example: `p(_1,_1)`

Comment: @false thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

The following code highlighting should make it clear why the goal `allocation(f1,f2,f3,f1,f2,f3,f2,f3)` cannot succeed:

```
allocation(Z1,Z2,Z3,Z4,Z5,Z6,Z7,Z8) :-
   dif(Z1,Z2), dif(Z1,Z3), 
   dif(Z2,Z3), dif(Z2,Z4),
   dif(Z3,Z4), dif(Z3,Z6),
   dif(Z4,Z5), dif(Z4,Z6), dif(Z4,Z7),
   dif(Z6,Z7), dif(Z6,Z8),
   maplist(frequency, [Z1,Z2,Z3,Z4,Z5,Z6,Z7,Z8]).
```

Note the use of `dif/2` instead of `(\==)/2` in the code above?

[prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif) preserves **[logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity)**, **for easier [debugging](/questions/tagged/debugging)**!